# airflow druid hook not working

Tags: hook, airflow, druid

I am trying to use druid hook to load data from hdfs to druid , below is my dag script :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json
from airflow.hooks import HttpHook, DruidHook
from airflow.operators import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import DAG

def check_druid_con():
 dr_hook = DruidHook(druid_ingest_conn_id='DRUID_INDEX',druid_query_conn_id='DRUID_QUERY')
 dr_hook.load_from_hdfs("druid_airflow","hdfs://xx.xx.xx.xx/demanddata/demand2.tsv","stay_date",["channel","rate"],"2016-12-11/2017-12-13",1,-1,metric_spec=[{ "name" : "count", "type" : "count" }],hadoop_dependency_coordinates="org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.7.3")

default_args = {
    'owner': 'TC',
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 8, 7),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}
dag = DAG('druid_data_load', default_args=default_args)
druid_task1=PythonOperator(task_id='check_druid',
                   python_callable=check_druid_con,
                   dag=dag)
```

I keep getting error , TypeError: load_from_hdfs() takes at least 10 arguments (10 given) . However I have given 10 arguments to load_from_hdfs , still it errors out . Please help.

Regards
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with function definition in airflow documents and actual definition in the code :

```
In documents it's defined as :
load_from_hdfs(datasource, static_path, ts_dim, columns, intervals, num_shards, target_partition_size, metric_spec=None, hadoop_dependency_coordinates=None)

But in reality the function definition is :
def load_from_hdfs(
            self, datasource, static_path,  ts_dim, columns,
            intervals, num_shards, target_partition_size, **query_granularity, segment_granularity**,
            metric_spec=None, hadoop_dependency_coordinates=None)
```

Passing correct arguments as per definition , took me out of this error.